# UICollectionView on iOS versions prior to 6.0

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm trying to build my project in new XCode 5.0 (Version 5.0 (5A11314m))

My project includes xib with UICollectionView.
The target of the project is iOS 4.3, but that xib will be displayed only in >=6.0.

During build i receive errors:

```
/* com.apple.ibtool.document.errors */
/Users/povolotskayalyubov/Documents/work/PF/Classes/SocialNetwork/FBPhotoThumbnailViewController.xib:9: error: UICollectionView on iOS versions prior to 6.0/Users/povolotskayalyubov/Documents/work/PF/Classes/SocialNetwork/FBPhotoThumbnailViewController.xib:17: error: UICollectionViewLayout on iOS versions prior to 6.0
```

How can i disable these checks to build project ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the file inspector of the XIB file, you can override the target OS settings to track a specific value instead of your build settings.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can.

In the build settings, you can set "Show errors" to NO in "Interface Builder XIB Compiler" section.